# On checked inbox it is not scrolling to the next div with id box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want that when I click on my checkbox they should be checked and automatically scroll down to next checkbox question. But In following code, it is scrolling down when input clicked but input is not giving the checked result.

On clicking in checkbox it is scrolling down but the checkbox is not checked??

```js
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('checked', true, function() {
    $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form id="form-contents">
    <div id="box1" class="box">
      <div class="contents-box">
        <label class="control-label " for="" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;">Question1</label>
        <br>
        <label for="">
          <input type="checkbox" href="#box2" name="checkbox1" >
          option1
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="">
      <input type="checkbox" href="#box2" name="checkbox2">
        option2
      </label>
        <br>
        <button class="scroll-link" href="#box2">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="box2" class="box">
      <div class="contents-box">
        <label class="control-label " for="" style="font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;">Question2</label>
        <br>
        <label for="">
          <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" >
          Good
        </label>
        <br>
        <label for="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
        Fine
      </label>
        <br>
        <Br>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything, as it has a syntax error.

Comment: Use prop instead of attr

Comment: Why are you including the `for=""` attribute on the labels if you are just leaving them empty? Also I don't think you are including everything in your snippet. I can check the box just fine. The example does not show your problem clearly.

Comment: you checkbox are checked ..

Comment: AuxTaco sorry bro but That code is working fine. Or do I need to mention HTML and head tags also?? I am new so I don't how things work here...

Comment: Your JS was missing a closing brace and paren. When Andrew Lohr moved your code into a snippet, e added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to do too much in your click handler. The natural effect of clicking on a checkbox is to toggle its checkedness; there's no need to do that yourself. Just worry about the animation:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).attr('href')) return;
  $('html').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
label { display: block; } /* so you don't need all those <br>s */
.box { margin-bottom: 500px; } /* to force a scroll bar */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box1" class="box">
  <h1>Question1</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" href="#box2">
    option1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" href="#box2">
    option2
  </label>
</div>
<div id="box2" class="box">
  <h1>Question2</h1>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Good
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    Fine
  </label>
</div>
```

I also added a line to bail out of the click handler early if there's nowhere to scroll to. It keeps your console free of errors.

Comment: Thank you So much, bro.  This is exactly what I was searching for. But can you please explain to me what this statement will do??                                     
  if (!$(this).attr('href')) return;

Comment: The checkboxes in the last question don't have a `href` attribute, so if you try to scroll to it, you'll get a TypeError. That line checks to make sure that there's a `href` attribute in the clicked checkbox, and if not, returns from the click handler without trying to scroll anywhere.

Comment: Ohkk Thanks, bro I get it.